# Trouble creating/using Maven repo type with the latest Community Artifactory Docker image ( artifactory-cpp-ce:latest )

Tags: docker, artifactory, vs-community-edition

My prior experience and my chat with JFrog Sales Engineer leads me to believe they still offer the prior repo types in OSS / community edition but all except Generic and Conan are greyed out for use/creation. Sales Engineering recommended I post here in case it takes them a while to get an answer.

Thanks All

[Main Config Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWZZC.png)

( docker image used ->
docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-cpp-ce:latest
061ee76788971cc300f4aa558d465fe98c01b0e3b76c993e48f070a3f0e0e2d0 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JFrog offers several OSS packages for Artifactory. Per your used image, you are pulling the artifactory-cpp-ce package, which is the Conan (C,C++) community edition, and that's why you only see Conan and Generic.

Other OSS packages are JCR (JFrog Container Registry, offering Docker, Helm & Generic) and OSS (offering Maven, Gradle, Ivy, SBT, Generic).

You read more about the JFrog OSS offering [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Comparison+Matrix).

Note: there's no single on-prem OSS Artifactory package supporting both Docker and Maven. You can register for the Artifactory cloud free-tier or go with Artifactory pro to get a single instance with all the supported package types

Comment: thank you very much. It was not clear to me or the jfrog chat SE that there were multiple discrete OSS bundles. that fully answers my question.